# How to get the value of Json line by line after converting python dataframe to a Json type

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have a python dataframe which i converted into json format.

```
result = df.to_json(orient='records'  ,  lines=True)
result 

Output:
{"candidate_id":101,"candidate_name":"Shrikanth Verma"} {"candidate_id":110,"candidate_name":"Shrishti Mehta"}
```

But How can i get the output where each row comes on new line.

```
Output: Required
{"candidate_id":101,"candidate_name":"Shrikanth Verma"} 
{"candidate_id":110,"candidate_name":"Shrishti Mehta"}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `print(df.to_json(orient="records", lines=True))` will print each record on new line.

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes that print command works, but actually i am building an api in which a function  returns the 'result' variable. So when the an api runs, the 'result' is displayed on single line. So how to deal with it in this situation , as i cannot use the print  in the api function.